# How to make bezier curves thicker so they are easier to see?

Tags: interface, bezier-curves, visibility

How can I make the bezier black lines easier to see? Basically I just want them thicker. They are super difficult to see against textured terrain and I need to constantly select all just to see where my lines are.

Also the handles are almost invisible and despite having set the brightness to max and colors as offensive as possible they still get easily lost because they are so tiny and narrow. Using the latest blender version.

Comment: You cant make them thicker right now. Apparently it's something that's under development. But you can change *Wire/Wire Selected* Color under 3D Viewport Theme Settings to at least make the curves themselves a brighter color, also consider changing the vertex size to something larger to make them stand out a bit.

Comment: You could add geometry to the curve and delete that before the render

Comment: Would temporarily increasing the bevel depth slightly under the Geometry > Bevel settings help?

Comment: @JohnEason I'd encourage you to write this as an answer. Even if it's just a workaround, it's still better than nothing.

Comment: Ok. I've now added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you could temporarily increase the <kbd>Depth</kbd> setting slightly on the <kbd>Curve</kbd> > <kbd>Geometry</kbd> > <kbd>Bevel</kbd> panel.

[image]